# How to display the verbose_name in html?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-admin

```
k2o = models.FloatField(verbose_name="K<sub>2</sub>O (wt%)")
```

I want to display verbose_name as html, like "K<sub>2</sub>O" in the admin page
but fail after trying format_html(). Is there any way to display the verbose_name in html?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use Unicode in the verbose declaration by prepending the string with `u`:

```
k2o = models.FloatField(verbose_name=u'K₂0')
```

and then you can use it directly in the template.